# Como gerar um link dinâmico dentro de uma condição no Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, link, thymeleaf

Gostaria de saber como posso gerar um link dentro de uma condição no Thymeleaf. Na minha situação, caso a condição não seja satisfeita, queria criar um link que direcionasse para um novo formulário, em que o usuário pudesse cadastrar um Diretor.

Eu já consegui realizar tarefas semelhantes em outras situações, mas somente dentro das tags de células das tabelas:

```
<td><a href="#" th:href="@{'movie' + '/' + ${movie.id} + '/show'}">Click Here</a></td>
```

Queria saber como fazer o mesmo no exemplo a seguir, atribuindo um link dinâmico para o texto 'Click Here to register':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <title>Star Wars Movies</title>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="container">
     <h2 th:text="'Episode ' + ${movie.movieName}"></h2>
     <p>You can add other movies through the StarWarsMoviesBootstrap class.</p>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Movie</th>
        <th>Box Office</th>
        <th>Release Date</th>
        <th>Director</th>
        <th>Characters</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td th:text="${movie.movieName}">The Force Awakens</td>
          <td th:text="${movie.boxOffice}">200000000</td>
          <td th:text="${movie.releaseDate.toString()}">???</td>
          <td>
            <span th:text="${movie.director != null} ? ${movie.director.directorName} : 'Click here to register'">Some value</span>
          </td>
          <td><a th:href="@{/{movieName}/characters(movieName=${movie.getMovieName()},movieId=${movie.id})}">View</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite, você poderia utilizar o if para verificar se existe e colocar o td de acordo com essa condição.

Por exemplo:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td th:text="${movie.movieName}">The Force Awakens</td>
    <td th:text="${movie.boxOffice}">200000000</td>
    <td th:text="${movie.releaseDate.toString()}">???</td>
    <td th:if="${movie.director != null}">
      <a th:text"'View Movie'" th:href="@{/{movieName}/characters(movieName=${movie.getMovieName()},movieId=${movie.id})}">Ver</a>
    </td>
    <td th:if="${movie.director == null}">
      <a th:text"'View Movie'" th:href="@{/register}">Registrar</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```